# unable to locate template folder

Tags: symfony4

How I try to install template on windows 10   it installed without any error but when i try to browser  displays error.

```
Using version ^1.0 for symfony/twig-pack
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.3.*"
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]
```

display on like this ..

```
Unable to find template "home/index.html.twig" (looked into: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject/templates).

Unable to find template "home/index.html.twig" (looked into: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject/templates).
```

Comment: do you have a file located at "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject/templates/home/index.html.twig"?